# Determine the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a problem when $n = 1$.  Is the question copied down correctly?

Comment: Oh sorry. Exactly from n=2.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!